# How can i make spinner hint?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I confused how can I make if I select `"A"` which appeared `"the Price"` after selected.

I don't know what it's called but for example like this:

How to if I select;

`1.05 which appeared 23,000`

`1.16 which appeared 25,000`

`1.26 which appeared 27,000`
?

```
final List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(0, "select");
        categories.add("1.05");
        categories.add("1.16");
        categories.add("1.26");

        final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        price.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        price.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("select"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"selected: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```